# Why is <a> tag overlapping the non-clickable region?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I verified that this behavior occurs ONLY on MacBook Pro. Actually, the "bleeding" of the  outside of its parent  occurs everywhere, but, except for MacBook Pro, it's not an issue that much... Just a couple of pixels.

I have a mystery I can't solve at the moment. Using:
Bootstrap 3 + some custom styling.

I have a phone number that should be clickable and a message underneath that shouldn't be. However, either the `<span>` or the `<a>` tag is going outside of its container and somehow overlapping the regular text "* Order Now". I selected the  tag in Chrome Developer Tools and that's what the picture below is showing:

[image]

Here is JSFiddle for this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/h1syL6hz/

Here is the complete code:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  background-color: blue;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#nav-list a {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav-list a span {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#phone {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#phone a {
  text-align: right;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#phone div { /* Order */
  color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

    </style>
  </head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br>Nav 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br>Nav 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br>Nav 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="phone">
            <a href="tel:555-555-5555">
              <span>555-555-5555</span></a><div>* Order Now</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
 
 
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi atque, nostrum, nihil labore pariatur ea incidunt voluptate porro fugit, a voluptates quibusdam provident nam rerum nesciunt necessitatibus quos velit distinctio.</p>
  
  <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: I just added the jsfiddle link. Thanks.

Comment: In which browser version do you have this problem? Do you probably have an extension installed that manipulates _phone links_  e.g. like Skype or similar.

Comment: I cannot see your problem(Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m and Mozilla 41.0.1)

Comment: I am using Chrome on a Mac: Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

I have copy paste your code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muyunogunu/edit?html,css) and I am not able to see as you had said.. here is the [output](http://output.jsbin.com/muyunogunu) and also a screenshot here..

I have not changed any code

[image]

still if you want to change than you can add `padding-top: 10px;` to css class `#phone div`

I have also seen in your fiddle and here is the screenshot :

[image]

Still if you are getting any problem then give your browser detail in which you are checking..

Comment: I just provided jsfiddle where you can see the issue.

Comment: I am using Chrome on a Mac: Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit). I don't have anything special installed for phone numbers. Just in case, I changed the "tel:555-...." to a regular http://somelink.com and it's the same behavior. Just tried on Firefox. Same thing. Not sure why you're not seeing it. Try rolling your mouse over the "* Order Now", starting from the bottom (blue section) and moving the mouse up towards the header section. Do you now see that it turns into a pointer ready to be clicked while it's still on top of the words "* Order now"?

Comment: This is so strange. I just tried it on a different Mac with the same exact dev setup as my other machine and the problem is not there... Well, to be exact, it's THERE, but in a *very* limited way. If you inspect the <a> tag, it's inheriting the line-height from bootstrap of 20px. That's smaller than needed for the text which is 1.8em (base is 16px). So, if you remove that line-height, the tiny bleeding of the span doesn't occur. However, EITHER WAY, I still don't understand why such a huge span bleed would happen... Any ideas?? I can try to re-install Chrome, but not sure that will do it.